# Determine when a PIXI texture is loaded to clone it

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm in the latest PIXI v5, where my texture is made like `let texture = PIXI.Texture.from(TEXTURE_URL)`.

The texture isn't loaded synchronously- Pixi just covers this up. That would be fine but when I try to apply a frame, the following error is thrown because the texture has no dimensions because it isn't loaded yet. I have no way of determining whether it's loaded or not!

```
Error: Texture Error: frame does not fit inside the base Texture dimensions: X: 8 + 8 = 16 > 0 and Y: 0 + 8 = 8 > 0
```

**How can I get a promise for when a Pixi texture is loaded or clone it anyway?**

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to pass the texture's dimensions into the `PIXI.Texture.from()` method.

```
let texture = PIXI.Texture.from('img/character.png', {width: 256, height: 256});
texture.frame = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, 86, 132);
// display texture here
```

**Character sprite sheet**

[image: character sprite sheet]

**After cropping with frame**

[image: cropped character sprite]

Other arguments accepted by `from()` can be found in [PixiJS Docs](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Texture.html#.from).

Answer (score 1):

Use [PIXI.Loader](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Loader.html), here's an example from that link:

```
const loader = PIXI.Loader.shared; // PixiJS exposes a premade instance for you to use.

// Chainable `add` to enqueue a resource
loader.add('bunny', 'data/bunny.png')
      .add('spaceship', 'assets/spritesheet.json');
loader.add('scoreFont', 'assets/score.fnt');

// The `load` method loads the queue of resources, and calls the passed in callback called once all
// resources have loaded.
loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    // resources is an object where the key is the name of the resource loaded and the value is the resource object.
    // They have a couple default properties:
    // - `url`: The URL that the resource was loaded from
    // - `error`: The error that happened when trying to load (if any)
    // - `data`: The raw data that was loaded
    // also may contain other properties based on the middleware that runs.
    sprites.bunny = new PIXI.TilingSprite(resources.bunny.texture);
    sprites.spaceship = new PIXI.TilingSprite(resources.spaceship.texture);
    sprites.scoreFont = new PIXI.TilingSprite(resources.scoreFont.texture);
});
```

For your convenience, these functions are also available:

```
// throughout the process multiple signals can be dispatched.
loader.onProgress.add(() => {}); // called once per loaded/errored file
loader.onError.add(() => {}); // called once per errored file
loader.onLoad.add(() => {}); // called once per loaded file
loader.onComplete.add(() => {}); // called once when the queued resources all load.
```

This way, when you call `new Texture(...)` with one of those assets, it will be initialised instantly, and its dimensions will be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wait (and keep polling) to see whether the texture dimensions have changed.

```
  async function() {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(texture.orig.width !== 0) {
          resolve();
        }
      }, 20);
    });

    // do things here, texture is loaded
  }
```